# Java: Swing Timer doesn't stop

Tags: java, swing, timer

Hey guys iam working on a Imageviewer but i have the problem that the swing timer doenst stop sending actionevents.
If i press the button "stop" it doenst stop the timer but enables the other buttons.

the diashow does work.

public class test3wegenDiashow extends JFrame implements ActionListener,MouseListener {

```
 ArrayList<Image> imagelist = new ArrayList<Image>();       //findet später das Image durch das zahlenarraylist
 ArrayList<Integer> zahlen = new ArrayList<Integer>();   // findet später das image welches angeklickt wurde 
Container c = getContentPane();
JButton b0,b1,b2,b3,b4;
JPanel p0;
JPanel p1;
JLabel l0,tester;
File file[];
int currentBild = 0;
Timer timer;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    test3wegenDiashow frame = new test3wegenDiashow();
}

public test3wegenDiashow() {
    super("Photoviewer");
    timer = new Timer(1000,this);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(800,800);
    Container c =getContentPane();
    p0= new JPanel();
    p0.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    p0.add(b0 = new JButton("Bilderauswahl"));
    b0.addActionListener(this);
    p0.add(b1 = new JButton("Vorwärts"));
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    p0.add(b2 = new JButton("Rückwärts"));
    b2.addActionListener(this);
    p0.add(b3 = new JButton("Diashow"));
    b3.addActionListener(this);
    p0.add(b4 = new JButton("Stop"));
    b4.addActionListener(this);
    c.add("South",p0);
    p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    c.add("Center",p1);
    b1.setEnabled(false);
    b2.setEnabled(false);
    b3.setEnabled(false);
    b4.setEnabled(false);
    setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton b = (JButton)e.getSource();
    String l = b.getLabel();

    if(l.equals("Bilderauswahl")) {                  //Bilder werden mittels JFileChooser in das Array file gespeichert.
        p1.removeAll();
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setDialogTitle("Bilderauswahl");
         FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPG UND GIF", "jpg", "gif");
            fc.setFileFilter(filter);
            fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
            fc.showOpenDialog(this);
            file = fc.getSelectedFiles();     // gewählte Datein werden 

            for(int i = 0;i<file.length;i++) {          //File Liste wird durchgegangen und es werden Images mithilfe des 
                if (file.length!=0) {                   // ImageIO.read Methode erstellt. Die Images werden anschließend
                try {                                   // in JLabels umgewandelt und dem Pannel übergeben.
                    Image image = ImageIO.read(file[i]);
                    imagelist.add(image);
                    image =image.getScaledInstance(155,155,java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);  //Skallierung
                    JLabel ladd = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
                    ladd.setText("Bild "+(i+1));            // Setze Text des Labels, um später im Array zu finden.
                    p1.add(ladd);
                    ladd.addMouseListener(this);
                    repaint();
                    revalidate();
                    pack();

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                 }
           }

            for (int z = 0;z<file.length;z++) {
                zahlen.add(z+1);
                                }
      }
if (l.equals("Vorwärts")) {
    try {
    if(currentBild >=0 && currentBild<file.length) {
        currentBild = currentBild +1;
        JLabel addit = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imagelist.get(currentBild)));
        p1.removeAll();
        p1.add(addit);

        repaint();
        revalidate();

    }
    } catch(Exception juckt2) {

    };

    }
if (l.equals("Rückwärts")) {
    try {
        if(currentBild>0 && currentBild <=file.length) {
            currentBild = currentBild -1;
            JLabel addit = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imagelist.get(currentBild)));
            p1.removeAll();
            p1.add(addit);
            repaint();
            revalidate();   
        }
    }catch(Exception juckt3) {

};
} if (l.equals("Diashow")) {
    b0.setEnabled(false);
    b1.setEnabled(false);
    b2.setEnabled(false);
    b3.setEnabled(false);
    b4.setEnabled(true);
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {      // was soll der timer machen     
                p1.removeAll();
                JLabel addit = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imagelist.get(currentBild)));
                p1.add(addit);
                repaint();
                revalidate();

                currentBild = currentBild + 1;
                if (currentBild>=file.length) {
                    currentBild=0;
                }
            }       
        });              
            timer.start();
        }
if (l.equals("Stop")) {
        timer.stop();
    b0.setEnabled(true);
    b1.setEnabled(true);
    b2.setEnabled(true);
    b3.setEnabled(true);
    b4.setEnabled(false);
}
    }


@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    String abfrage = ((JLabel)e.getSource()).getText();
    try {

    for(int y=0;y<=file.length;y++) {



    if (abfrage.equals(("Bild ")+ zahlen.get(y))) {
          b1.setEnabled(true);
          b2.setEnabled(true);
          b3.setEnabled(true);
          b4.setEnabled(false);


        JLabel addit = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imagelist.get(y)));
        p1.removeAll();
        p1.add(addit);
        currentBild = zahlen.get(y);

    repaint();
    revalidate();
    pack();
    }
    }
    }catch(Exception juckt) {

    }
}


@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
```

in the `actionPerformed()` method of the class you declare a new `Timer` variable instead of using the already declared static one.
Just remove the `Timer` from the line i.e.

```
timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
```